# Create a Random position nearby for my object 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object, random, 3d

I am trying to do a random position nearby the initial position. I have been searching and working on many hours of doing this.
I wasn't be able to do this. I manage to use the script from unity https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitCircle.html and it makes my object to go too far away..

I have search and here about random object positon but I didn't find anything helpful.
Please if you could help me I would be greatful

Comment: What exactly is your issue? RandomInsideUnitCircle should work for inside a 2D circle. Use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitSphere.html For a 3d position.

Comment: I want to use random x position for my object .Everytime I play to have a different place to be

Comment: You only want a random x? Just do something like new Vector3(Random.Next(),something,something);

Otherwise if it is too far away, you can divide. Random.InsideUnitSphere will always provide a point exactly 1 unit from the origin or 0,0,0

Comment: yes  I want only this .Any example do you have ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Change the 5 to something smaller:

```
void Start()
{
    transform.position = Random.insideUnitCircle * 1.1;
}
```